# Is it possible to add a company logo to the recept email PayPal sends out?

Tags: paypal

As far as I've been able to gather you can only co-brand the checkout process, but the  PayPal documentation is fairly convoluted. Has anyone managed to put a logo on the actual emails paypal sends out?

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the payment pages by specifying header & footer URLs. However, there's no way to change the actual receipt email customers receive.

*But*, if you have some programming ability, you can <s>just disable the default email receipt that PayPal sends out, then</s> use the [IPN API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro) to send out your own receipt, which you can customize and make however you want.

**Edit:** There's no way to disable or customize the payment notification emails PayPal automatically sends customers after they make a purchase at your store. So the only way to send a custom-branded email receipt without the customer receiving 2 purchase confirmations is to use a proper payment gateway.

Comment: I have used the IPN API in the past to send out e-mails with additional information to the purchaser, but wasn't aware that you could actually disable the PayPal receipt.

Comment: @Sherwin: Upon further investigation, it appears that your initial impression was right. There's no way to disable the PayPal notification. Authorize.net and other payment gateways have this option, so I simply assumed that PayPal had this option as well. But I guess the notification e-mail isn't really something PayPal is sending on behalf of PayPal merchants, but rather more like a bank statement PayPal provides PayPal consumers.